# For portrait orientation on Tabs

Tags: android, orientation, tabs, android-tabhost

I would like to restrict my application which uses Tabs to portrait orientation. I have 4 tabs and I set the  "android:configChanges="orientation" for all 4 tabs but the orientation still changes when i rotate the phone. Seem pretty straight forward. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: The key item missing from your tags... "android"

Answer (score 0):

After further review, just needed to add the following to the manifest :

android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Thanks